# Scaled ellipse over button, button not clickable

Tags: wpf, c#-3.0, button, wpf-controls, ellipse

I'm scaling an ellipse in an animation with the following code:

```
        ScaleTransform myScTransform = new ScaleTransform();
        TransformGroup myTransGroup = new TransformGroup();
        myTransGroup.Children.Add(myScTransform);
        newPHRadio.RenderTransform = myTransGroup;
        newPHRadio.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(0.5, 0.5);

        Storyboard story = new Storyboard();
        DoubleAnimation xAnimation = new DoubleAnimation(1, ph.Bereik, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)));
        DoubleAnimation yAnimation = new DoubleAnimation(1, ph.Bereik, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)));
        DoubleAnimation doorzichtig = new DoubleAnimation(1, 0, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2)));

        Storyboard.SetTarget(xAnimation, newPHRadio);
        Storyboard.SetTarget(yAnimation, newPHRadio);
        Storyboard.SetTarget(doorzichtig, newPHRadio);

        DependencyProperty[] propertyChainX = new DependencyProperty[] {
           Ellipse.RenderTransformProperty, 
           TransformGroup.ChildrenProperty,
           ScaleTransform.ScaleXProperty
        };

        DependencyProperty[] propertyChainY = new DependencyProperty[] {
           Ellipse.RenderTransformProperty, 
           TransformGroup.ChildrenProperty,
           ScaleTransform.ScaleYProperty
        };

        string thePath = "(0).(1)[0].(2)";

        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(xAnimation, new PropertyPath(thePath, propertyChainX));
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(yAnimation, new PropertyPath(thePath, propertyChainY));
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(doorzichtig, new PropertyPath(Ellipse.OpacityProperty));

        story.Children.Add(xAnimation);
        story.Children.Add(yAnimation);
        story.Children.Add(doorzichtig);

        story.Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60 / ph.Frequentie));
        story.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;
        story.Begin();
```

The ellipse is constructed with the following code:

```
        Ellipse newPHRadio = new Ellipse();

        newPHRadio.Width = 1;
        newPHRadio.Height = 1;
        newPHRadio.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, ph.xPositie + 7);
        newPHRadio.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, ph.yPositie + 7);
        newPHRadio.SetValue(Canvas.ZIndexProperty, 3);

        newPHRadio.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
        newPHRadio.StrokeThickness = 0.03;
```

Now the ellipse is scaled over an button which has a z-index of 1. With a static ellipse and no fill, the button is clickable. Now there is no fill as well but the button is not clickable. Can someone tell me how to fix this?

Comment: "With a static ellipse and no fill, the button is clickable. Now there is no fill as well but the button is not clickable." ??? Didn't understand this. Do you mean your button is not clickable when your ellipse is filled?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
Sorry if I'm not clear, English is not my first language.


I have a button which has a z-index of 2. On top of that button I have a ellipse with no fill and a z-index of 3 (Left part of the picture). The button is clickable in this case.

Now I have the same button and the same ellipse. I use the code above to scale the ellipse (right side of the picture). Now the button is not clickable.


The picture can be found here: http://xs.to/image-6A50_4BE86908.jpg


I hope you understand my question now :)

Answer (score 0):

With the code you provided the button is clickable.

But if you set the Fill of the ellipse to anything but null, even to Brushes.Transparent, the click will not make it to the button anymore.

Try explicitly setting the Fill of the ellipse to null:

```
newPHRadio.Fill = null;
```